# Site for programming patterns and practices

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is there any discussions site about good patterns and practices in programming (better in C#) among the Stack Exchange Q&A sites?

Code reviews not discussions about it?

Comment: What do you mean with “Code reviews not discussions about it?”?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Programming practices](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/programming-practices/info) are on topic on [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/); for code reviews, there is, well, [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Note, however, that no Stack Exchange really focusses on discussions but rather on questions and answers.